# When I try to run npm test with mocha, in my cmd it says "Error: Cannot find module 'path' " does anyone know how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, solidity

When I try to run npm test with mocha, in my cmd it says `Error: Cannot find module 'path'`

I am a total beginner in this area and just trying to write some really simple code. I am using Mocha as my test frame, it worked totally fine yesterday and today it's down.

I tried `npm install -D @types/path`, it did not work out.

Here is my code in Inbox.test.js file:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');//capitalize when working with a constructor function
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());//local instance
const {interface, bytecode} = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;
beforeEach(async ()=>{
    //Get a list of all accounts
    web3.eth.getAccounts()
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    //Use one of the accounts to deploy 
    //the contrct
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments:['Hi there!']})
        .send({from: accounts[0], gas:'1000000'});//account[0] is the one
        //who is really deploying the contract
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', ()=>{
        console.log(inbox);
    });
});
```

Here is code in my compile.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contract', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];
```

The test frame Mocha should run through my code and print out the smart contract I created, instead it shows a error that says I am missing a module 'path'.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'path '
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\compile.js
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\test\Inbox.test.js
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\one-and-dones.js
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\options.js
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Alex Zhu\Desktop\Inbox\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you use require('path ') with space after it name inside apostrophe. The error message show it Error: Cannot find module 'path ' After the space removing, what is the new error message?

Comment: Have you got the sol file at this location:

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contract', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

Comment: Hi sarkiroka, I have removed the extra space and nothing happened. And yes, I double checked my Inbox.sol file it is in the right location.